# How to create a link to apple store and playstore?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, app-store

I want to create a link that redirect user on the right store to download my app. If an iphone user click on the link it will redirect him on appstore.

Can you help me ?

Comment: if you try to go on the online playstore with a computer and you go to the section of the app you wan't to show you can copy the link and if you put it on a android app when you open the link it will automatically open the play store app. For my app i did it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to detect the platform on which user is using your app. Then on the basis of that platform you can handle the specific click event.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, use an Intent as followed :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=<APP_PACKAGE_NAME>"));
startActivity(intent);
```

`APP_PACKAGE_NAME` is the package name of the app you want to link to

On iOS, I think you can use `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()`